# MVC Core 2 external users and access token

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, access-token, identityserver4

i am new with Dot net core 2 and implementing MVC client & IdentityServer4.

facing two problems while getting external user access token.

**problem 1**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
             { 
                 options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 //options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
             })
```

when adding below line of code

```
options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
```

user not able to login even after successful authentication in **ExternalLoginCallback**

**Problem 2**

If i removed above line of code, the user can login but `await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token")`
returns null.

Here is the complete code for startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        { 


             services.AddAuthentication(options =>
             { 
                 options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                 //options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;   

             })
           .AddCookie()
           .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
           {
               googleOptions.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientId"];
               googleOptions.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Google:ClientSecret"];
               googleOptions.SaveTokens = true; 
           })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            { 
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:xxx/";  
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;  
                options.ClientId = "xxx"; 
                options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";  
                options.Scope.Add("xxxx");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.SaveTokens = true;


            });

            services.AddMvc();
        } 
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute(); 
        }
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the start up from my mvc web app that connects to Identity Server 4.  Note the `.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)`

Setup.cs

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
             .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                //options.DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp-keys\"));
                // when the identity has been created from the data we receive,
                // persist it with this authentication scheme, hence in a cookie
                options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                // Identity server endpoint
                options.Authority = settingsSetup.IdentityServerEndpoint;
                // Turns off HTTPS requirement becouse i CBA to set up visual studio.
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                // Client id to login with
                options.ClientId = settingsSetup.ClientId;
                // Client secret.
                options.ClientSecret = settingsSetup.Secret;

                // Scope of our API
                options.Scope.Add("testapi");
                options.Scope.Add("devconsole");
                // adding offline_access to get a refresh token
                options.Scope.Add("offline_access");

                options.ResponseType = "code id_token";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
            });
        services.AddAuthorization();
```

From your controller you should be able to get the values this way.

```
var accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.AccessToken);
var refreshToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(IdentityConstants.HttpContextHeaders.RefreshToken);
var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync(OpenIdConnectParameterNames.IdToken);
```

Comment: Thanks DalmTo, i did the same and user can login successfully, but bot functions returns null.


`var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");`

Comment: Whats the Identty server logging say?  Can you see your user logged in?

Comment: `var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }`

Comment: after successful login and redirect, user not get logged in

Comment: if we remove this line from startup.cs

'options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme'

then user get logged in successfully.